# How to get object keys which have common value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

I've a problem getting object keys by value for example:

```
issues: {
  window_expired: 'Yes',
  no_power: 'No',
  no_display: 'Yes'
}
```

I want to get object keys which have 'Yes' Value as: window_expired, no_display

I've tried this method which is working but it's returning the 1st key i want to loop through and get the keys by value:

```
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find((key) => object[key] === value);
}
```

Comment: Use `filter` instead of `find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use filter in your case.

`Object.keys(issues).filter(e => issues[e] === 'Yes')`

Have a good day